# Ray intersection with cylinder of arbitrary rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, intersection-theory

I'm working on writing an algorithm for a the distance of a ray intersection with a cylinder (t), where the cylinder is of arbitrary rotation. Using [this website](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) as inspiration, I know I can find the intersection by solving the following for t:

Where the ray is described by: $x(t) = p_r + tr$ and the cylinder has $x_1$ and $x_2$ describing two points on its central axis and a radius r,

$$
\frac{|(x(t) - x_1)\times (x(t) - x_2)|^2}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} = r^2
$$

However, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I can code solving for t into my algorithm, even after I've expanded everything. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this or suggest an alternative solution to the problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a little bit nasty expression. I would start by opening the parenthesis on the cross product, and one obtains
$$
(x(t) - x_1 ) \times (x(t) - x_2) = p_r \times (p_r + x_1 - x_2 ) + x_1 \times x_2 + t (x_1 + x_2 )\times r + t^2 (r \times r)
$$
Which doesn't really look much simpler ... Then one should calculate the length of this ... ugh!

Comment: For anyone still attempting this problem: It's not too bad! It's the best way to approach the ray-cylinder intersection problem in my opinion (unless you are an ultimate master of linear algebra) - just remember your cross product rules as you simplify :)